HuggingFaceからLLMモデルを取得して追加学習ようとしたときにエラー
Windows11 Pro + Python 3.11 + VSCodeの環境で、LLMモデルに追加学習をさせるプログラムを作成しようと試みているのですが、エラーが発生しています。
原因をご教示いただきたく、よろしくお願いいたします。
やりたいこと
HuggingFaceからLLMモデルを取得して、CSVファイルを追加学習させたい。
やったこと

VSCodeのターミナルから huggingface-cli login を実行
HuggingFaceのアクセストークン(hf_***********)を入力
VSCodeで後述のlearning.pyを作成し、実行

起こった問題
以下のエラーが発生
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\learning\learning.py", line 6, in <module>
    model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained(model_name)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File >"C:\Users\airep\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\transformers\models\auto\auto_factory.py", line 566, in from_pretrained    
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Unrecognized configuration class <class 'transformers.models.llama.configuration_llama.LlamaConfig'> for this kind of AutoModel: AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.
Model type should be one of BartConfig, BigBirdPegasusConfig, BlenderbotConfig, BlenderbotSmallConfig, EncoderDecoderConfig, FSMTConfig, GPTSanJapaneseConfig, LEDConfig, LongT5Config, M2M100Config, MarianConfig, MBartConfig, MT5Config, MvpConfig, NllbMoeConfig, PegasusConfig, PegasusXConfig, PLBartConfig, ProphetNetConfig, SeamlessM4TConfig, SeamlessM4Tv2Config, SwitchTransformersConfig, T5Config, UMT5Config, XLMProphetNetConfig.

補足事項

「やったこと」の手順2までを実行した時点で、「Token is valid (permission: read).」が返されています。
transformersとdatasetsのパッケージのpipインストールはしてあります。
ソースファイル(learning.py)の9行目に記述されているcsvファイル"documents.csv"は、learning.pyと同じパスに置いてあります。

ソースコード
learning.py
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM, Trainer, TrainingArguments
from datasets import load_dataset

model_name = "elyza/ELYZA-japanese-Llama-2-13b"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained(model_name)

# Load your CSV dataset
train_dataset = load_dataset('csv', data_files=['./documents.csv']) 

# Define training arguments
training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir='./results',  # Output directory
    num_train_epochs=3       # Adjust based on dataset size
)

trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=train_dataset,
    tokenizer=tokenizer
)
trainer.train()


llama2ベースのモデルを使っているためにllamaconfigというconfigが使われていて、AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained()がこのllamaconfigに対応していない、ということがエラーメッセージから読み取れたので、AutoModelForSeq2SeqLMの代わりにAutoModelForCausalLMを使うことで上記のエラーは解消しました。ただし別のエラーが出てしまいます。データセットの形式に起因すると思われるエラーです。
